# ionic 3 geo-location not working for the second time

Tags: android, ionic3

I have a problem using `Geolocation` on `Android` device.

I create an `Ionic 3` application.
I use `Geolocation` ( [https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/ 13]).
I use the sample code provided there.
The problem is that, the code works in Browser but whenever I upload it on an `Android` device, it does not work.

When I start the app on device the alert for location permission is prompted.
I press Allow.
Then in the android tray an icon appears that says “Searching for GPS”.
After timeout expires I got the error for timeout and no location.

The strange think is this:
If I close my app, then open `google maps` ( or other app using `gps` position ) and reopen my app works as it should.

I don’t know what to do.

The permissions are fine :

and everything was installed properly.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it actually i have to pass apikey with that like

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
```

in the index page

without this key it sometime works but not sure everytime.

Note : this key is only generated when you have a valid gmail a/c (by providing DOB/CreditCard nos) although its free .

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

**--prod** makes production build apk

Answer (score 0):

import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';

declare var navigator
Above
@Component

watchPosition() {

```
     this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
        () => {
                var options = {
                    timeout: 500,
                    maximumAge: Infinity
                };

                this.watch = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((data) => {
                    let latlng: LatLng = new LatLng(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);


                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("error watch", error)
                }, options);

            }
        }, error => {
            alert('Error requesting location permissions' + JSON.stringify(error))
        }); 
}
```

}